# Hide Parameter Value of @Url.Action MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, href, url.action

I am working on MVC5 Application At some situation  I want to hide the parameter value in url

I am using like below code:

`<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {ID=@item.ID})"></a>`

Any proper way to hide id and its value in url or any alternate way for acheive the same

Can anybody please provide me some inputs on this? it will be greatly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer is no. If you do not send the value from the browser to the server, how would it know what it is.

Comment: is there any alternate way to achieve it

Comment: Not making a GET. But why would you want to hide it anyway. And how would anyone navigate to that method if its expects a value for `id` and they do not send it.

Comment: That makes no sense. You handle security in the code in your controller method.